# How can I differentiate between strings and non-strings (function calls, numbers)?

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I'm writing a tool in [go](/questions/tagged/go) which essentially tracks db changes and generates SQL of the changes that occurred since the last time the app ran. I fully understand that there are probably better ways to achieve this but I'm simply using this as a learning experience.

---

Assume the following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "my_db";
```

I realised that if I wanted to get a accurate representation of `COLUMN_DEFAULT`, I needed to differentiate between `NULL` as a value and a random string within the `COLUMN_DEFAULT` column and so I used `sql.NullString` to achieve that:

```
rows, err := conn.Query(...)

for rows.Next() {
    var columnDefault sql.NullString

    _ = rows.Scan(..., ..., &columnDefault)

    // Not null:
    // Could be a string e.g. Hello, World! 
    // Could be a function call e.g. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    // Could be a number e.g. 1
    // So you the following would not be valid
    if columnDefault.Valid {
        columnDefault = "'" + columnDefault + "'"   
    }
}
```

But then, again, I realised that I also need to differentiate between strings and other data types/values within `COLUMN_DEFAULT` e.g. `COLUMN_DEFAULT` = `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, `COLUMN_DEFAULT` = `1`, or `COLUMN_DEFAULT` = `Some random string...`

So, is there a native way that I can differentiate between strings and a non-strings (e.g. function calls, numbers etc. which I wouldn't quote)

Answer (score 0):

If `COLUMN_TYPE` is the type of the row I guess you could check for the value of that in the go code. The best solution for you is to save the type and then check what it is. Normally you would not want to put different types of data in a `varchar` column though.

If you want to make the sql query return no NULL values, add `AND COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL` to the end before the semicolon.